# Why does my touchscreen not respond, when changing the primary monitor to a non-touch external monitor?

Tags: multi-monitor, xinput, touch-screen

I have a `Lenovo Thinkpad Helix` with a Linux running on top of it. Over the miniDP I connected a regular Dell monitor.

All is well as long as the Helix stays the primary monitor, but if I switch the primary monitor to the Dell, I can not dispatch any touch events with my Helix.

Using `xinput --test [device]` with the device id of the touchscreen does not show any events, after switching, but does so before.

Using `xinput --map-to-output <HelixName>` does not change anything for some reason.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: It works for me with Ubuntu 15.10 and a ThinkPad Helix 2. Running xinput --test 'Wacom HID 5014 Finger touch' shows the events. How are you switching to the new display? I use xrandr --output eDP1 --off --output HDMI2 --mode 2560x1600.